# Segmentation Fault besides memory allocation

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out why my assignment to an char * [] is giving me a segmentation fault when I try and assign a value to [0].

So what I mean is, I created a

```
char * temp[255]
```

which should allocated space in the heap for the temp. Thus when I do

```
while(buffer)
{
    for(num = 0; num < i; num++)
    {
        if(strcmp(temp[i], buffer) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* send menu choice to server indicating client wants list of all files on server */
    if (sendto(sock, menuOption, sizeof(menuOption), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("sendto() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
    }

    /* receive a response from the server */
    fromSize = sizeof(fromAddr);
    if ((recvDataLen = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromSize)) < 0)
    {   
        printf("recvfrom() failed\n");
    }

    if(serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr != fromAddr.sin_addr.s_addr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: received a packet from unknown source.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* null terminate the received data */
    buffer[recvDataLen] = '\0';
    strcpy(temp[i], buffer);
    i++;
    printf("%s\n", buffer);    /* Print the echoed arg */
}
```

I should not be getting a segmentation fault, because i is initialized to 0 (I have not shown the initialization here because i is set at the top of my file along with socket attributes). So in the first iteration of the while loop, the for loop does nothing because num and i are both zero, thus it proceeds to send data to the server and retrieve data from the server. That data is put into buffer and should be then copied into temp. However it just gives me a segmentation fault and crashes. Any ideas why?

Comment: `char * temp[255]` allocates space for 255 pointers to `char`. However from the code you show those pointers point to nowhere, will say had not been initiliased.

Comment: I think, you mean to do, `char temp[255]`

Comment: nothing. temp array is declared at the top along with other attributes. Its declared as follows: char * temp[255];

Comment: @alk so then why do i get a segmentation fault if there is space on the stack? Segmentation faults occur when you try and access a memeory location you don't have access to correct?

Comment: That `for` loop doesn't increment `i` ...

Comment: All you've shown is an array of 255 uninitialized pointers.  Show us the init code.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `char* temp[255];` is not what you think. It is an array of 255 **pointers**. Not strings. Your pointers are uninitialized so they point to completly random places, which causes your segmentation fault. To Avoid this you need to allocate memory for every pointer.

```
char* temp[255] = {0}; // set all pointers to 0
//...
for(num = 0; num < i; num++)
{
   if(temp[i] != 0 && strcmp(temp[i], buffer) == 0) // if a pointer is 0 (uninitialized), do not access it
   {
      break;
   }
}
//...
temp[i] = malloc(size); // probably (strlen(buffer) + 1) (except you use something else for buffer)
if(temp[i] == NULL)
{
// something bad happend.
}
strcpy(temp[i], buffer);
```

Comment: why did you do malloc for temp[i]?

Comment: So you still have the copypastaed non-i-incrementing `for`-loop.

Comment: why should it increment i?

Comment: I didn't meant to say you shall increment `i`. I just wanted to point you to this useless loop. ;-)

Comment: the temp[i] in the for loop should be temp[num]. That was my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You have declared an array of 255 pointers:

```
char * temp[255];
```

So you can do the following with these:

```
char actual_data[5] = {0};
strcpy (actual_data, "Heya");
temp[0] = actual_data;     //temp[0] now points to "heya"
```

But you cannot do:

```
strcpy (temp[0], actual_data);
```

This is because temp[0] is a pointer and does not have any memory of its own other than 4/8 bytes (equal to an integer). If you want to strcpy then you need to allocate memory. You can do something like:

```
char actual_data[5] = {0};
strcpy (actual_data, "Heya");
char *temp[255];
for (i=0; i<255; i++) 
{
     temp[i] = (char *)malloc (sizeof(actual_data) * sizeof(char));
     strcpy (temp[i], actual_data);
}
```

This is just an example where all the 255 pointers will point to actual_data (hence "heya").